# Download folder with Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have some data on Google Drive, organized in folders, which I want to propagate on other servers. I have some script for propagating, but I need to download data from google drive. Is there a method for downloading folders via Google Drive API, that is also maintaining whole folder structure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Folders are also files on Google Drive.  The only difference is the Mime type. with folders its `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`.

There is no single method that will allow you to download everything with in a folder.  Your going to have to do a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) searching for the files with the parent Id to the file Id of your parent folder using search parameters (TIP: [''1234567' in parents'](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)).  This will return a list of the files contained within your folder.  Then download each one.

Update from comment you need to loop though each directory or just do a main list of everything on your drive account and process the data locally.

> File 1 (folder)
>  
>   ----> File 2 (folder )
>   --------> File 3 (actually a file)
>   ---->File Four (actually a file)

```
'File 1' in parents
```

returns everything within the file 1 directory.   If the mime type of the item returned is a directory `(mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')` make a request to get its contences

> 'File 2' in parents

returns everything within the file 2 directory.

Comment: Thank you. But what about downloading file that is not a direct child of specific folder? `'file_id' in parents` matches only direct children

Comment: try playing with Not   (not 'file_id' in parents) should bring back all files not in that directory.

Comment: What I meant is to get `file3` from structure `file1 -> file2 -> file3`, knowing only `file1`. `parents` field in Drive API contains only direct parent

Comment: your going to have to make a request for each sub directory.  use the results from the first request to request the data from subsequent requests.

Answer (score -1):

```
FileList result = service.files().list().setQ("parents='1NzSAZEwAFARWegk42ANrWQrTopWQTdGB'").setSpaces("drive")
                    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                    .setPageToken(pageToken)
                    .execute();
```

The `parents` parameter is the the `fileId` of the folder you want to download files from. Doing this you can get all files in that particular folder.

Comment: Hi, if you want to improve your answer, you can put your code in a code block. It will be more readable. Moreover, the code seems incomplete; for example `pageToken` is not defined, and the folder contents is only listed, not downloaded. Is recursivity handled ?