# Download whole Folder (google drive api)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-drive-api

Hey guy's I have an google drive app.
Where I can download upload and many more things.
The problem is that I need to be able to download the "folder" as well.

So the scenario is:

```
Folder1
-FolderA
--fileA1
--fileA2
--FolderAA
---fileAA1
---FileAA2
---FolderAAA
----FileAAA1
-FolderB
-FolderC
--FileC1
```

If I click on download folder 1 I want it to download all the things u see
If I click on download folderC he only download Folderc (or zip) with filec1 in it.

The files are easy to download because they have `webContentLink`

I already read:

[Download folder with Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184940/download-folder-with-google-drive-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download folder with Google Drive API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184940/download-folder-with-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do a [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) which will return a list of each of the files.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "incompleteSearch": boolean,
  "files": [
    files Resource
  ]
}
```

Loop though each of the files and download it.   If you are after a way of doing it in a single request then there isn't one.  You will need to [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) each file one by one.

Comment: Hmm there is no other solution then downloading 1 by 1 ? 
Thnx for the fast reply

Comment: That is the only option.  I do agree it would be nice if we could batch download a full directory.   However google leaves that up to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Although question is already answered, I had a similar situation and wanted to share some code. The code recursively digs through folders and saves the files in the exact hierarchy.

The code is C#, but also pretty much self-explanatory. Hoping it might do some help.

```
private void downloadFile(DriveService MyService, File FileResource, string path)
{
    if (FileResource.MimeType != "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
    {
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        MyService.Files.Get(FileResource.Id).Download(stream);
        System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(path + @"/" + FileResource.Title, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        stream.WriteTo(file);

        file.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        string NewPath = Path + @"/" + FileResource.Title; 

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(NewPath);
        var SubFolderItems = RessInFolder(MyService, FileResource.Id);

        foreach (var Item in SubFolderItems)
            downloadFile(Item, NewPath);
    }
}

public List<File> RessInFolder(DriveService service, string folderId)
{
    List<File> TList = new List<File>();
    var request = service.Children.List(folderId);

    do
    {
        var children = request.Execute();

        foreach (ChildReference child in children.Items)
            TList.Add(service.Files.Get(child.Id).Execute());

        request.PageToken = children.NextPageToken;
    } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

    return TList;
}
```

Note that this code was written for API v2 and `Children.List` is not there in API v3. Do use `files.list` with `?q='parent_id'+in+parents` if you use v3.